# Is there a way in Python to remove title headers in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a list of files that I am supposed to combine and do some data analysis on. The problem with these files is that they contain Titles. I am familiar with `pd.read_excel` but I am not sure how do I remove the titles. You can look at this attached image. There is like 12 extra files doen the same. So I do not think that spending time deleting the rows is practical. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Something like `pd.read_excel(skiprows=5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le [read_excel itself](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) has some good facilities:

**skiprows**: let you to cut out useless information (on top)

**header**:  you can use it to load all titles into a Multiindex. You can decide to ignore it or use in some manner.

Comment: Thank you @Glauco. That solved my problem actually. If I export Excel files with a logo in it and use it (company standard format), should I still use Skip rows or need to remove the logo image?

Answer (score 1):

pandas.read_excel( header=0(remove header),or  skiprows=(specific row number))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).